# How to rename a list in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Is it possible to rename a list in Sharepoint 2007 using the web interface? I would like navigation url to change as well.

I have tried change the name using the settings option on the list. This will change the title but not the navigation url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure that changing the url is possible through the web UI.

However, you could probably save the list as a template, include the content as part of that template, and then delete the list. Finally, apply the template to get a newly named (with new url) list.

Comment: I've done this and it works, however, list item creators and create dates get reset to whoever created the new list, and when it was created.

Comment: This is a long-winded way of doing it with several downsides, I would use one of the other methods described.

Comment: This has way too many side effects and downsides, most notably you'll lose any type of auditing. I'd definitely recommend the answer provided by [Shane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805005/how-to-rename-a-list-in-sharepoint/3445372#3445372)

Answer (score 20):

I had this same issue and I resolved it easily in SharePoint Designer. You have to go to All Files listing, find the list, right click and Rename.  This will change the URL.  You won't have this option if you go to the List & Libraries option, you have to go to the All Files one.

You cannot do this in the Web UI.

Also, another tip. If you need you have a need to name a list with spaces, but don't want the ugly %20 escape characters in the URL.  Say you need to name your list Info Center.  First create the list with no space:  InfoCenter.  Then go back and rename the Title only to Info Center.  Now you will have the a nice readable list name, as well as no %20's in your URL.

Comment: I think this is a better solution than doing it programmatically or saving the list as template and creating a new list. For detailed steps you can check http://www.thesharepointblog.net/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=815f255a%2Dd0ef%2D4258%2Dbe2a%2D28487dc9975c&ID=52

Comment: Excellent answer and the least invasive of all the other answers provided. This should definitely be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can definitely change the URL using [SharePoint Designer](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepointdesigner/FX100487631033.aspx). 
I'm quite sure you can also do this programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

The list will get the name you created it with so create the list and then set the localised name afterwards

```
if (site.Lists.Exists(Constants.MyListName, out myList))
{
    myList.Description = Resources.My_Lists.My_List_Description;
    logger.Write("List {0} already exists on site {1}", Constants.ListNames.MYLIST,site.Url);
}
else
{
    Guid listGuid = site.Lists.Add(Constants.ListNames.MYLIST,   
                    Resources.My_Lists.MyList_List_Description,
                    SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary);
    myList = site.Lists.GetList(listGuid, false);
    logger.Write("Created list {0} on site {1}", Constants.ListNames.MYLIST, site.Url);
}
myList.NoCrawl = true;
myList.Title = Resources.My_Lists.My_Inbox_List_DisplayName;
myList.EnableVersioning = true;
myList.EnableMinorVersions = false;
myList.Update();
```

When you then need the list you get it using the internal Name which will be the same name as in Constants.ListNames.MYLIST

```
list = (from SPList l in web.Lists
                        where l.RootFolder.Name.Equals(listInternalName, StringComparison.InvariantCulture)
                        select l).FirstOrDefault();
```

I think it is a good practice to stay away from the Display name see this article regarding problems with fields in Sharepoint

http://www.buro9.com/blog/2007/02/26/sharepoint-splistitem-quirks/

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can change the url in Windows Explorer. The library/list still exist and can be edited.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, you start working with a list naming it as Beta list, test, site version 1 etc and then you realize that you need to change the name of the list. Here's the step by step procedure for changing the name:

1. Click "Site Actions" and select "Site Settings"
2. Under "Site Administration" select "site libraries and lists"
3. Select the list you want to customize
4. Under General Settings select "Title, description and navigation"
5. Edit the name and you are through.

This should not modify the hyper connections and various views of the list.

Comment: This seems like a more correct way to achieve the desired result, and doesn't require additional software.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Sharepoint, but I have successfully renamed a list. This is what I did:

- Created a "Network Place", which is
  actually a WebDAV location for the
  site
- Renamed the list in Windows Explorer
- Removed/Added the "new" list to the
  Quick Launch.

The URL is changed, as the old name is no longer valid.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The internal name for lists is pretty messy and killing it in code or by manipulating the files may break some custom web parts, workflows, or cause orphaning. For these reasons, I would leave the internal name alone rather than risk causing something to break in the name of vanity. If the client was requesting the change, however, I would save the template as Martin says and use that to rename your list.

Answer (score 0):

Once you create a list or doc library, the url cannot be changed using the web interface - you're stuck with it unless you modify it using something like Powershell or SharePoint Designer.

I highly recommend making it a habit to initially create the lists/libraries with a shortened/clean url, then immediately renaming the lists/libraries to its "nice" name for everyone to read clearly.